# Unity3D Rigidbody Constraints Get Property

Tags: unity-game-engine, constraints

I'm trying to do simple things on Unity3d, and one of these things is to check whether Rigidbody Constraints has Enabled Freeze Position X,Y,Z angles. I check in net but all Q was how to add properties and couldn't find how to get property. I would be glad if someone can tell me.

Answer (score 2):

for x-position it should be:

```
if((rigidbody.constraints & RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX) == RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX) 
{
    // x-position is frozen
}
```

see http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.html for the other options

also try searching for bitflag tutorials :)

edit: fixed missing brackets

Comment: error CS0019: Operator `&' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.RigidbodyConstraints' and `bool' ::: when i do the following code

Comment: You're right, i missed a pair of brackets, the compiler compared RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX with RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX which is obviously true and then tryed to apply the &-operator which led to: if(rigidbody.constraints & true)

Comment: not working ... same problem operator & cant be casted on constaints

Comment: Thats strange because this time i tryed it out before posting and it worked for me, maybe you could post that part of your code